# c# fastest way to do bitwise operations on large block of bits

Tags: c#, performance, bit-manipulation

I have a set of arrays of hundreds of thousands flags `0` or `1`.

I'm using the `BitArray` class for doing something like that:

```
result = (BitArray)ab.Clone();
result.And(bc);
```

many many times...

Of course I have to set the flags in `Bitarray` first.

```
for (int i = 1; i < maxLen; i++) ab[i] = a[i] < b[i];
```

But when I set the flags once then I'm doing thousands of operations `and`, `or`, `xor`, `not` on them (so the speed of the bitwise operations is much more important)

And again from the beginning.

I'm asking you if is in C# faster method for doing this?

Comment: You should easily be able to figure out which method is faster using  the [`Stopwatch`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class to time real results in your application.  This will be much more accurate than anything we can give you.

Comment: ofc.... but give me a metod to compare it with ...

Comment: I thought you were asking if it is faster to use `BitArray.And` compared to looping over all the bits and using `&` on each bit pair.  If that isn't what you are asking about, please clarify your question.

Comment: this method is about 350 times slower - so no ... i'm looking for something different - maybe memory streams, or something - give me idea to looking for

Comment: Is the expense in the clone? If so, you might consider using an immutable persistent data structure; the overhead you get in the structure being larger and more complicated is paid for in the cloning operation being zero cost.

Comment: somebody tells me that i should try with biginteger - i try - but its two times sslower than bitarray

Answer (score 4):

Assuming GPU isn't an option, your best bet will be `Vector<byte>` on a CPU that supports SIMD operations. There are methods in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` that allow you to load a `Vector<T>` from an unsafe pointer (specifically: `Unsafe.Read<Vector<byte>>`), allowing it to be used very efficiently against arrays pinned via `fixed`. Or: wait until `Span<T>` is mainstream, and use `NonPortableCast<byte, Vector<byte>>`

Comment: @barpas yes; the package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/ - the .NET JIT has had inbuilt recognition of `Vector<T>` for some time now, emitting optimized SIMD instructions automatically. Remember to check whether your hardware supports it - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.vector.ishardwareaccelerated(v=vs.111).aspx